# EnvDTE Remove class attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte, vspackage

I have a very simple query (EnvDTE), "how do I remove an attribute from a class".

```
[Authorize]
class SomeController
{ ... }
```

I tried -

```
authorizeAttr.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint().Delete(authorizeAttr.EndPoint);
```

it works but leave empty square brackets.

```
[]
class SomeController
{ ... }
```

I simply want to remove attribute, the complete line (the way it should be). Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 of your class and then remove attributes in a loop like this:

```
EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 codeClass;
...
while (codeClass.Attributes.Count > 0) {
    ((EnvDTE80.CodeAttribute2)codeClass.Attributes.Item(1)).Delete(); // Attributes array starts from 1 not 0
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [MyCustom("Example 1", 1), MyCustom("Example 2", 2)]
    public class MyForm : MyBaseForm
    {
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(617, 450);
            this.Name = "MyForm";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    [Designer(typeof(MyBaseFormDesigner), typeof(IRootDesigner))]
    public partial class MyBaseForm : Form
    {
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MyBaseForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(391, 337);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        public MyBaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int IntValue { get; set; }

        public MyCustomAttribute(string text, int intValue)
        {
            this.Text = text;
            this.IntValue = intValue;
        }
    }

    public class MyBaseFormDesigner : DocumentDesigner
    {
        public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
        {
            base.Initialize(component);
            Verbs.Add(new DesignerVerb("Remove Attributes", OnRemoveAttributes));            
        }

        protected virtual void OnRemoveAttributes(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            EnvDTE._DTE dte = GetService(typeof(EnvDTE._DTE)) as EnvDTE._DTE;
            EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 codeClass = GetCodeClass(dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements, "MyForm");
            while (codeClass.Attributes.Count > 0) {
                ((EnvDTE80.CodeAttribute2)codeClass.Attributes.Item(1)).Delete(); // Attributes array starts from 1 not 0
            }
        }

        private static EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 GetCodeClass(EnvDTE.CodeElements codeElements, string name)
        {
            EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 codeClass = null;
            foreach (EnvDTE.CodeElement item in codeElements) {
                if (item.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass) {
                    codeClass = item as EnvDTE80.CodeClass2;
                } else if (item.Kind == EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) {                    
                    codeClass = GetCodeClass(((EnvDTE.CodeNamespace)item).Members, name);
                }
                if (codeClass != null && codeClass.Name == name) break;
            }
            return codeClass;
        }
    }
}
```

To test this example compile it, open MyForm in designer mode, right click on form and select "Remove Attributes", all attributes from MyForm should be removed.